# Error importing tensorflow, libcudnn.so not locateable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to get Tensorflow working, but when I try to validate the installation with the example from their guide, it returns an error. Here is the full output:

```
uburobot@uburobot:~$ source /opt/tensorflow/bin/activate
(tensorflow)uburobot@uburobot:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Installation path is /opt/ where I placed cuda and also tensorflow. *$ locate libcudnn.so.5* returns me nothing. Versions are Cuda 8.0 and cuDNN 5.1.
Everything besides this is functional. I used the nvidia guide to install Cuda and verified the installation with the given examples (worked). Adding *export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/* to bashrc doesn't do anything.

Comment: If your `CUDA_ROOT` is `/opt/cuda` then adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64` to your bashrc wouldn't do anything because thats not where you installed cuda.

Comment: I also have a folder in /usr/local named cuda and another one named cuda-8.0. Sry but I am a linux noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, the default installation path of cuda is `/usr/local/cuda` and `/usr/local/cuda-8.0`.If your cuda was installed in the default path, you could export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/ to bashrc or add `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64` to the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf, then run `ldconfig` in the terminal.

Your cudnn library may be installed incorrectly. You need copy the cudnn.h to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/include, then copy the libcudnn_static.a and libcudnn.so.5.1.5 to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64. run

`cd /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.5.1.5 libcudnn.so.5
sudo ln -s libcudnn.so.5 libcudnn.so`

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. It worked. Just for clarification, if another person has this problem and is a linux noob like me: The last commands have to be executed while in that file path, so cd to /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 and run the commands.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Robot.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tensorflow cannot find the cuDNN shared object file(s).  Which means you either didn't copy it to the correct place or your .bashrc isn't setup correctly.  Assuming you've installed cuda to `/usr/local/cuda` then I have my .bashrc setup like this:

```
export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/lib64
```

make sure your source your .bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And then make sure that your cuDNN shared objects are in the correct place.

```
~$ cd cuda/
~/cuda$ ls
include lib64
~/cuda$ cp include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
~/cuda$ cp lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

then rebuild tensorflow.